# mouseover background "highlight" covering text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a navigation bar where the background highlights when you mouseover it, but when I do this, the text also becomes highlighted and is no longer visible (barely).

Here is my current HTML and CSS:

```
<header>
    <img id="logoimg" src = "./images/home.jpg">
    <ul class="top-nav">
            <li><a href=''>Home</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href=''>Products</a></li>
    </ul>
c</header>

.top-nav {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #296E9A;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.top-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #296E9A;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.top-nav a {
    line-height: 200%;
    color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.top-nav a:hover {
    background: #000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.05;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your CSS on the `a:hover` has an opacity of 0.05, which is causing the text to be barely visible.

```
.top-nav a:hover {
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 0.05; /* remove this */

    background: rgb(36, 105, 147); /* fallback for IE8 support */
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05); /* add this for highlighting */
}
```

Remove the opacity property and your text should appear when you hover your mouse over the navigation link.

Add the `background: rgba()` to set a background color with alpha transparency (this affects the background only, not the text or any children nodes).

Also keep in mind that rgba() supports modern browsers but lacks support for IE8 and below.  You'll have to apply `rgb()` or any other color value as a fallback for compatibility support.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/3yf2Q/2/

Thanks @setek :)

Comment: Worth noting that OP probably doesn't want the highlight background colour to be black, but just a slightly darker blue. It would be good to change `background` property to: `background: rgb(36, 105, 147); background: rgba(0,0,0,0.05);` like here: http://jsfiddle.net/3yf2Q/2/

Comment: @setek You've nailed it.  I suppose I didn't understand the question the first time around.  `rgba(0,0,0,0.05)` is the way to go when setting opacity on only the background.  This won't work for IE8 and below unless you apply a fallback.  I'll update my answer.

Comment: thanks! removing the opacity easily solved it. I never tried it without it before that..

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the opacity since it applies to your text as well, or just specify opacity: 1; for the li portion to maintain some kind of highlight.

```
.top-nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100px;
    background: #296E9A;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 5px;
    opacity: 1;
}
```